# Process of texturing a model

Tags: texturing, uv, workflow, normal-map

I've modeled a dragon and I now want to texture it.

I'm stuck in thinking where I should start and how I should proceed. I already have done the UV-mapping of my creature. As I want my dragon to have scales, I've been wondering whether I should create a normal map in blender (by drawing each scale on my own) or create some kind of procedural texture (in Substance Designer 5).

Here's an image of my creature:
[image: dragon with no textures]

Comment: As it currently stands this question is not very suited for StackExchange, because it is too broad and opinion based. There are just too many possible good answers for this. Try something like the Blender Artists forum at http://blenderartists.org/ which is much more suited for this type of question. Once you start your texturing work, if you have any more specific doubts or particular difficulties you can come back here and ask a more focused direct question.